# Updating a live project

Tags: mysql

**Situation:**

1. I've just deployed the first version of my website (in PHP with
   MySQL database). I now need to move to version 2 of my website.
2. I typically build my website on localhost before moving it to the production server
3. I now want to restructure my database. But I'm not clear how to do this without losing / corrupting existing user data.
4. I'm worried that WHILE I'm making the above changes, a user may try
   to make edits to the database.

**Questions for you**

1. Let's say I restructure my database in localhost. How do I duplicate
   this restructuring on the live server? Do I need to run every query
   on both localhost and production servers? (Seems very inefficient -
   is there a better way to do this?)
2. How do I make sure that while I'm restructuring the database, the
   sanctity of the data is not harmed (i.e. how do I make sure the
   "version" of the database does not change until I finish my job?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a "migration script" in sql that collects all queries required to migrate a database between two states. You try that how often required in your development environment and once on the production environment.

During that migration of the production environment you enable a "maintenance mode" that prevents any changes to the data being made and clearly states so to the user. Be transparent here. Two variants are in use:

1. you block all requests and temporarily replace the site by a "maintenance sign", this is typically done if the migration only takes a very short time. If that is not sufficient, then
2. you have to implement a read-only or maintenance mode into your logic rendering all data as read-only. Again: be transparent to you users in this.

If that is all too much hacking, then you might want to learn from the "big players" who *never* manipulate running systems at all, but only switch between instances, often a pool of instances. So you prepare a second, new system and only switch to that at a given point in time. Still you have to take care of a read-only period to allow data synchronization, but the switch itself is fast and reversible.